# Epimorphism from $3\mathbb{Z}$ to $U_8$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

I'm trying to disprove/prove that an epimorphism exists from $3\mathbb{Z} $ to $U_8$

$U_8$ is acyclic, and is composed out of $\{1,3,5,7\}$. Therefore I can't map every $3k \in 3\mathbb{Z}$ to a cycle, so I'm thinking of creating a composition $f(x) = h(g(x))$ such that:
$$g(x) = x \mod 12 \\ h(0) = 1, \: h(3) = 3,\: h(6) = 5,\: h(9) = 7 $$

However I'm stuck proving this is even an homomorphism.

Comment: So, $U_8 = (ℤ/8)^×$, yes? Anyways: As you say yourself, $U_8$ is acyclic. But if $f \colon 3ℤ → U_8$ is a group homomorphism, what can you say about its image?

Comment: @k.stm Yes, the multiplicative group of integers modulo n

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since all the elements of $U_8$ have order $2$, all the even elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ must map to $1$:$$f(2k)=f(k+k)=f(k)\cdot f(k)=1$$
Suppose that $f(3)=x$.  Then $f(-3)=x^{-1}$  Now all the positive odd elements of $3\mathbb{Z}$ map to $x$,
since $$f(3(2k+1))=f(6k)f(3)=x,$$and all the negative odd elements map to $x^{-1}=x$, so $f$ cannot be onto.

Comment: Can you explain why every positive odd element of $3\mathbb{Z}$ must map to the same $x$?

Answer (score 3):

Consider these:

- $3 \mathbb Z$ is a cyclic additive group.
- A homomorphic image of a cyclic group is cyclic.
- $U_8 \cong C_2 \times C_2$ is not cyclic.